# Working on GitLab/GitHub/BitBucket feature branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, gitlab

I am looking for a recommended methodology of working on a feature branch in Git with a server like BitBucket/GitLab/GitHub.

Assume we start with a release on the master branch, create a feature branch and assign several developers to work on it. They clone the repository to their respective workstations and start working. If all of them make changes on the same branch, how do they avoid a conflict?

Comment: Sometimes conflicts cannot be avoided.  There is nothing wrong with 3 developers sharing a branch if you don't expect big conflicts.  If the work being done by each developer is logically distinct from each other, then consider creating three separate branches.

Comment: The question is re-phrased to be a "how to".

Comment: To avoid a conflict, your developers should not do things which will cause Git to raise conflicts.  So things like two developers refactoring the same method at the same time, or massively changing the same areas of a class at the same time.  An good example of what would _not_ cause a conflict would be one developer making a UI change while another developer makes  a server side change.  Different files, no conflicts.

Comment: What if there is an overlap between the areas? For example, when there is an include or parameter file that both developers are using.

Comment: Then you may get a conflict.  But what you want to aim for are conflicts which are easily resolvable.  The example I gave of two developers both touching the same method in the same class will likely lead to a bad conflict.  Git is like drinking beer, have a glass and you feel good, have a 40 and you feel bad.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't have you developers create a branch off of your feature branch?

The advantages would include flagging any conflicts in a pull request
and running any automated tests before merging content into a protected branch: https://help.github.com/enterprise/admin/guides/developer-workflow/about-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks/